# Assign arbitrary attribute to MVC model's property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC web application I have the bellow class:

```
public class LoginVM
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string password { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

And in cshtml file I use EditorForModel to generate the form:

**.cshtml**

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Now I want to know that is there any way to add some arbitrary attributes(for example css class attribute) to the html tag that is generating automatically?

Something like this:

```
    ...
    [Required]
    // Some code like this: [addAttribute("class", "myCssClass")] 
    public string Username { get; set; }
    ...
```

Comment: Sure, but you would have to write a custom attribute and view.

Comment: It would make little sense. A property can be rendered by any template, consisting of zero or more HTML elements. To which elements should the CSS class be applied? - Use an EditorTemplate instead.

Comment: why would you like to hard code your stylesheet classes in the model class?  it kind of breaks the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Comments by CodeCaster and Thorarins. It's not a good idea to mix up your Model with View related Attributes. In addition to using EditorTemplates/DisplayTemplates, you could also use the [`UIHintAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.uihint(v=vs.110).aspx). It can help you to switch between different formats or also stylings within the View.

Some example:
http://www.shawnrenner.com/asp-net-mvc-custom-property-display-using-uihint/

Comment: Just to elaborate: `EditorForModel` will utilize an editor template, if one exists, to render the fields for the model. As a result, all you need to do is create the view `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\LoginVM.cshtml`, and you can define exactly how the fields should be rendered.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Agreed. The UIHint Attribute will help you, if you want this kind of customization on a detailed level, like for a single input only.